# codenameone - L10N not work in dialog

Tags: localization, dialog, codenameone

I am using codenameone for my mobile application. I use custom L10N dictionary on it and when I want to show one of these keys in `dialog` page it doesn't show that. Here is sample:

```
Dialog.show("Info", "errPassEmpty", Dialog.TYPE_INFO, 
            res.getImage("notification_error64.png"), "OK", 
            "Cancel", CommonSettings.TimeOut);
```

How can I show L10N values in `dialog`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which text isn't localized? Did you install the resource bundle correctly?

Comment: The Message, Second parameter. Yes I installed it correctly. I'm going to double check, maybe I have a mistake.

Comment: Did you invoke UIManager.getInstance().setResourceBundle(Hashtable) with your bundle?

Comment: no, I will do it. I think I had a problem like this. I try to solve it. Thanks a lot. I thinks I should invoke UIManager.getInstance().setResourceBundle(Hashtable) as you said.

Comment: @Shai I do it as you said. Thanks, it's my fault.